# Typescript - Replacing strings in url map

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a map like so:

```
const urlPaths = {
        "Signature": "signature/(signatureId)",
        "Rule": "signature/(signatureId)/rule/(ruleId)",
    };
```

I then have some data that comes in my API like:

```
aId: {
    signatureId: "999"
}
```

or

```
aId: {
    signatureId: "123",
    ruleId: "456"
}
```

I want to be able to use that map, to return me the url for Signature or Rule, for example:

`"signature/999"` or `"signature/123/rule/456"`

I've come across the regex replace, but wondering, can I actually use that in this case?

```
function createUrl(url, regex, aId){
   url.replace(regex,(id) => aId[id])
}
```

Not sure if its possible/how to do with that or do I need something else?

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that a `RegExp` is strictly necessary, since the patterns you want to replace match the names of your properties. You could do something like this:

```js
const urlPaths = {
  "Signature": "signature/(signatureId)",
  "Rule": "signature/(signatureId)/rule/(ruleId)",
};

const aId1 = {
    signatureId: "999"
};

const aId2 = {
  signatureId: "123",
  ruleId: "456"
};

const createUrl = (url, aId) => {
  let newUrl = url;
  Object.entries(aId).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    newUrl = newUrl.replace(`(${key})`, value);
  });
  return newUrl;
}

console.log(createUrl(urlPaths.Signature, aId1));
console.log(createUrl(urlPaths.Rule, aId2));
```

If you do want to use a `RegExp` though, here's an example of how that could work too

```js
const urlPaths = {
  "Signature": "signature/(signatureId)",
  "Rule": "signature/(signatureId)/rule/(ruleId)",
};

const aId1 = {
    signatureId: "999"
};

const aId2 = {
  signatureId: "123",
  ruleId: "456"
};

const createUrlRegExp = (url, regexs, aId) => {
  let newUrl = url;
  const replacer = match => aId[match.slice(1, -1)]; // get rid of parentheses around match
  regexs.forEach(regex => {
    newUrl = newUrl.replace(regex, replacer)
  });
  return newUrl;
};

console.log(createUrlRegExp(urlPaths.Signature, [/\(signatureId\)/], aId1));
console.log(createUrlRegExp(urlPaths.Rule, [/\(signatureId\)/, /\(ruleId\)/], aId2));
```

Answer (score 1):

As the poster asks for a Typescript solution, here I'm providing a Typescript solution. You don't necessarily need for regexp here, as the [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts a string as a pattern also.

```js
interface AID {
  signatureId: string,
}

interface AIDWithRuleId extends AID {
  signatureId: string,
  ruleId: string,
}

interface UrlPaths {
  Signature: string,
    Rule: string,
}

enum ValuesToReplace {
  signatureId = '(signatureId)',
    ruleId = '(ruleId)'
}

class URLBuilder {
  private static urlPaths: UrlPaths = {
    Signature: `signature/${ValuesToReplace.signatureId}`, // or you can keep "signature/(signatureId)"
    Rule: `signature/${ValuesToReplace.signatureId}/rule/${ValuesToReplace.ruleId}`, // or you can keep "signature/(signatureId)/rule/(ruleId)"
  }


  static getSignatureUrl(data: AID): string {
    return this.urlPaths.Signature.replace(ValuesToReplace.signatureId, data.signatureId);
  }

  static getRuleUrl(data: AIDWithRuleId): string {
    return this.urlPaths.Rule
      .replace(ValuesToReplace.signatureId, data.signatureId)
      .replace(ValuesToReplace.ruleId, data.ruleId);
  }

}

let x1: AID = {
  signatureId: '1'
};
let x2: AIDWithRuleId = {
  signatureId: '1',
  ruleId: '1'
};

console.log(URLBuilder.getSignatureUrl(x1));
console.log(URLBuilder.getRuleUrl(x2));
console.log(URLBuilder.getSignatureUrl(x2));
```

Comment: I just stuck with the syntax OP used, assuming that they don't have many strict compiler flags enabled, but good point